# Minimal parabolic subgroups are $G(k)$-conjugate: a cohomological interpretation?

Tags: algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, reductive-groups, nonabelian-cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected,reductive group over a $p$-adic field $k$.  Let $M_0$ be a minimal Levi subgroup of $G$, and define $M_0^{\operatorname{der}}$ to be $M_0 \cap G_{\operatorname{der}}$.  Lemma 2.1 of [this paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyushujm/57/2/57_2_383/_pdf/-char/en) by Takuya Konno on the Langlands classification for $p$-adic groups comes down to showing that

$$H^1(k, M_0^{\operatorname{der}}) \rightarrow H^1(k, G_{\operatorname{der}})$$

is injective.  He claims that this is equivalent to Proposition 4.7 and Theorem 4.13 of the article *Groupes Reductifs* by Borel and Tits.  These results are about conjugacy of minimal parabolics and Levis for a reductive group $G$ over an arbitrary field $k$:

> **Propostion 4.7**: Let $P,P'$ be two parabolic $k$-subgroups of $G$.  Then $P \cap P'$ contains a maximal torus defined over $k$.  Every connected $k$-closed subgroup of $P \cap P'$ is defined over $k$.  In particular, $P \cap P', \mathscr R(P \cap P'), \mathscr R_u(P \cap P')$ are defined over $k$.  The group $P \cap P'$ has Levi $k$-subgroups, and any two of them are conjugate by a unique element of $\mathscr R_u(P \cap P')(k)$.
>
> **Theorem 4.13**: Let $P, P'$ be two parabolic $k$-subgroups of $G$.
>
> a) The fibration of $G$ by $P$ has a local section defined over $k$; the projection $G(k) \rightarrow G/P(k)$ is surjective.
>
> b) If $P$ and $P'$ are minimal (among parabolic $k$-subgroups), they are conjugate over $k$.
>
> c) If $P$ and $P'$ are conjugate over an extension of $k$, then they are conjugate over $k$.

I don't understand the connection between these results and the claim in the lemma.  How can one interpret these results about the conjugacy of minimal parabolics as as a statement of injectivity of the $H^1$ sets?

Comment: Name of article, and DOI link: [A note on the Langlands classification and irreducibility of induced representations of $p$-adic groups](https://doi.org/10.2206/kyushujm.57.383).

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity we write $G$ for $G^{\rm der}$ and $M_0$ for $M_0^{\rm der}$, then $G$ is a connected reductive group, and $M_0$ is a Levi subgroup of a minimal parabolic $P_0$ of $G$.
Let $$\xi\in{\rm ker}[H^1(k,M_0)\to H^1(k, G)]$$
be a cohomology class, represented by some 1-cocycle $c\in Z^1(k,M_0)$.
Since $\xi=[c]$ is contained in the kernel, the exists $g_1\in G(\bar k)$
such that $c_\sigma=g_1^{-1}\cdot \,^\sigma g_1$ for all
$\sigma\in \Gamma:={\rm Gal}(\bar k/k)$.
We set
$$M_1=g_1\cdot M_0\cdot g_1^{-1},\quad P_1=g_1\cdot P_0\cdot g_1^{-1},$$
then one can easily check that $M_1$ and $P_1$ are defined over $k$.
Since $(P_1,M_1)$ is conjugate to $(P_0,M_0)$ over $\bar k$, we see that $P_1$ is a parabolic of $G$ and that $M_1$ is a Levi subgroup of $P_1$. By Theorem 4.13(c) $P_0$ is conjugate to $P_1$ over $k$:
$$P_0=g\cdot P_1\cdot g^{-1}\quad\text{for some }g\in G(k).$$
Set $g_2=g g_1\in G(\bar k)$,
then
$$g_2 \cdot P_0 \cdot g_2^{-1}=P_0\,,$$
hence, $g_2\in N_G(P_0)=P_0$.
Now since $^\sigma g=g$, we notice that
$$c_\sigma=g_2^{-1}\cdot \,^\sigma g_2\,,$$
so we see that
$$\xi\in{\rm ker}[H^1(k,M_0)\to H^1(k,P_0)].$$
Since $H^1(k,P_0)= H^1(k,M_0)$, see e.g. Lemma 1.13 in
Sansuc, J.-J. Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres. J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80,  we conclude that $\xi=1$, hence
$${\rm ker}[H^1(k,M_0)\to H^1(k, G)]=1.$$ A twisting argument shows that every fiber has only one element.

Comment: Link to the Sansuc paper: [Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1981.327.12).